# How to play with a dachshund that cannot chew toys?

Tags: dogs, toys

My mini doxie has been dealing with a broken lower jaw, on both sides,  for a while.  She has metal plates holding it together,  so it was able to heal but it's already "healed" and re broken once before so I'm afraid to try to get her into toys that involve too much chewing or tug of war.  Having said that,  I'd still like her to be able to play with toys.. does anyone out there have any ideas or suggestions for toys that would be gentle on her poor little jaw?

Comment: Plush toys might be a good start. Sorry for your doggy's situation, and thank you for caring so much